# object properties displayed in storyboard and its corresponding property name in the actual implementation class

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, storyboard

I'm currently learning how to use storyboard to configure my UI.

I know that when you drag out a object e.g. `UIButton` from the object library, the utitlies window on the right usually display properties/variables associated with the dragged out object.

e.g. for `UIButton`, I can configure properties such as `buttonType` (`Type` in storyboard) , `currentTitle` (`Title` in storyboard) either programmatically or using the storyboard column. (Note that the actual property name in the implementation classes and the corresponding name for the same property in the storyboard is sometimes different)

[image]

But for `UIButton`, in the "identity inspector", I have noticed a property named `Restoration ID`, but I can't seem to find the corresponding property in the [UIButton documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton). So is there a way I can programmatically set/change the `Restoration ID`?

[image]

And in general, if I see a property in the storyboard utility window, what is a good search strategy to find out the corresponding property name in the actual class?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: hi @Rob, thanks for the tips! Correct me if I'm wrong, but is it correct to assume that every property that appears in the storyboard utility window can be found in the actual implementation class, whether it would be the class itself or any of its superclass. Is there any exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check superclasses, too, e.g. [`restorationIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622494-restorationidentifier) for `UIView`.

Re finding property name, you can try hitting <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> (the letter "Oh", not zero) and start to type the name. Or go to symbol navigator (<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>), type in some string you want to search for (e.g. restoration), and make sure to uncheck the "show project symbols only" and "show class/protocol symbols only" options next to the search box at the bottom of the symbol navigator.

FYI, while most of the storyboard properties correspond to some property of the underlying class, but not all. IIRC, there are a few exceptions, such as the "Document" section of the "Identity Inspector" or the "Installed" checkbox on the "Attributes Inspector". There might be others, too.